# Notify the Spring bean to be re-created

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have a problem where we need to force a spring session bean to be recreated with the initial configurations specified in configuration xml file.

And all autowired dependencies should point to newly created bean. Is that possible to do anyhow with Spring framework? Or could you suggest any method to do this?

Comment: You could try ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh(), invalidate http session or not to use session scope(I would prefer this one). Also, it's not really clear why would you ever need to do that.

Comment: @white Suppose it is application context bean. Will ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh() refresh also all autowired dependencies which depends on this bean? Also I think it will cause some performance and memory leak issues

Comment: ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh() will recreate all singletons in context, and yes, it is not recommended to use, unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing. It would be better, if you described your problem, not a way you are trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create another `temporary` bean in your context, and use it in your conditional case. unfortunately, I will have to call `getBean()` method to reassign my reference to the temp bean.

For example:

In your configuration file, you will have to define two beans:

```
<bean id="originalBean" class="x.y.z.MyBean" />
<bean id="temporaryBean" class="x.y.z.MyBean" />
```

And in your beans that reference that bean you will have to autowire using the @Qualifer

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("originalBean")
private MyBean myBean;
```

And in your conditional use case you will reassign that reference to the `temporaryBean`

```
if(conditioalCase) {
    myBean = ApplicationContext.getBean("temporaryBean");
}
```